# How to fix discolored logs in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Recently, I have begun to mod Skyrim. It can be quite fun and make one's game significantly better, but at the same time, sometimes there are issues. The following screenshot was taken in "The Bannered Mare" in Whiterun:

[image: Fire in the center of "The Bannered Mare"]

As you can most likely see, the logs are discolored. This is not a game-breaking issue, though it is quite annoying. I have searched the Internet for fixes, and have thus far come across no fixes other than one which does ameliorate the issue; the location of which is:

http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8236/?

================

## ADDITIONAL NOTES

-I have also seen this issue in civil war camps, which I assume is because it uses the same "campfire" asset.

-The list of mods in load order (list from LOOT):

-0  0 Skyrim.esm

-1  1 Update.esm

-2  2 Dawnguard.esm

-3  3 HearthFires.esm

-4  4 Dragonborn.esm

-5  5 HighResTexturePack01.esp

-6  6 HighResTexturePack02.esp

-7  7 HighResTexturePack03.esp

-8  8 yetikillkids.esp

-9  9 EnhancedLightsandFX.esp

-10  a ELFX - Exteriors.esp

-11  b mintylightningmod.esp

-12  c WondersofWeather.esp

-13  d Distant DetailHF.esp

-14  e SkyFalls + SkyMills + DG + DB.esp

-15  f RealisticWaterTwo.esp

-16 10 ELFXEnhancer.esp

-17 11 Pureweather.esp

-18 12 SFO - Expanded Diversity.esp

-19 13 RealisticWaterTwo - Legendary.esp

-20 14 SMIM-Merged-All.esp

-21 15 TrueStorms.esp

-22 16 TrueStorms-PureWeather.esp

-23 17 Supreme Storms.esp

-24 18 TrueStorms-SupremeStorms-Vanilla.esp

-25 19 Skyrim Flora Overhaul.esp

-26 1a Verdant - A Skyrim Grass Plugin.esp

-27 1b DragonFire-Dragonborn.esp

-28 1c Skysan_Icicle.esp

-29 1d HighResTexturePackFix.esp

-30 1e dD-No Spinning Death Animation Merged.esp

-31 1f Brawl Bugs CE.esp

-32 20 BFSEffects.esp

-33 21 Disenchanting.esp

-34 22 SeeEnchs.esp

-35 23 SkyUI.esp

-36 24 dD - Enhanced Blood Main.esp

-37 25 dD-Dragonborn-Dawnguard-EBT Patch.esp

-I have done the necessary cleaning with TES5Edit, it did not resolve the issue nor did it create it (the issue was present before I cleaned).

-Based on several Google searches, I believed the issue to be associated with the High Resolution Texture Pack, though removing it did not resolve the issue

==========

## CONCLUSION

I would appreciate any advice as to how to resolve this issue. I would like to refrain from anything that removes the all mods I have, but if it is 100% necessary I may just ignore the issue (because it is not game breaking), though it is quite annoying.

======

## UPDATE

Firstly, I would like to explain that I have followed the advice given to me by those who replied which sadly, did not work. I also tried using the "Verify integrity of game cache" feature on Steam which also ended in failure. I am going to try and get a clean game (by deleting my current Skyrim files and re-installing.) Hopefully, that will work, and if it does I can just re-install my mods later. Thank you to those who replied to my question, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: You can disable the last half of the mods and check if it fixes it. If not disable the last half of the remaining ones and continue until it fixes, then reenable the last set you disabled one at a time until you figure out which mod is causing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Dragonrage is right. Discovering which mod changes/conflicts is a long and tedious process, and usually results in the misbehaving mod being the last one you check.

Comment: Do something called a "Binary search".  Basically, just split the search regions in half.  It's not too bad if you do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a fair number of mods in there alter lighting source textures and also alter the game lighting itself and provide specific altered textures to match the new lighting. That's going to be a pain to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, resetting Skyrim's files seemed to solve the issue. All my mods have be re-installed and they seem to be working nicely. I have no idea what caused the problem considering all my old mods are working as they are supposed to. For anyone else who needs to fix this: remember to backup your files before resetting. Thank you all for responding to my question!

Comment: Knowing Skyrim, you may never learn what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the mods that have textures. They might've affected the textures of the logs. If that doesn't work, you might need to delete other mods that might affect this.

Answer (score 0):

The fire and chopping wood block fix which you have linked to is the same that is fixed by [this mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23351/?#). (*At least that's what I used, basically on the day it came out*). However, that fix is for what you can see in the following image - caused by the HighResTexturePacks. I don't believe the image you post is the same problem.

[image: example]

I also vaguely remember seeing that green/yellow crap on the logs - but in any case I looked for better fire-pit textures in general. Any of them *should* get your fires looking better as long as it loads after anything else which messes with fire textures (ie: load it last) - but this is the one I used.

[Better Embers](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23352/?)

[image: example2]

Of course, maybe you don't want to continually load up on mods to fix the issues of other mods and you'd rather eliminate the culprit to begin with. In that case, you should follow the advice (given in comments) to search for which mod is causing the problem. You have a lot of FX mods in your list, and I would try disabling the majority of those as a first place to start.